# Posterior probability that the effect has opposite direction

Tags: hypothesis-testing, bayesian, posterior

In hypothesis testing under Bayesian paradigm, I came across an idea to compute probability that the effect has the opposite direction than observed. For example, when testing null hypothesis that expected value of random variable is zero and observing that point estimate is above zero, it is the area of posterior density above negative half-axis.

Is it reasonable to use this statistic?

Does it have a name? I was unable to find it in literature.

Comment: Sounds like Type S error to me, see e.g. http://andrewgelman.com/2004/12/29/type_1_type_2_t/

Comment: hejseb: Man, thank you! I was searching for its name for months. This is the first trace leading somewhere.